# how to restart spring batch failed job with old job paramters

Tags: spring-batch, jobs, restart

I am passing time in my job parameters .After running my job , i can see in console my job started with time parameters :-

Job: [FlowJob: [name=DB2-SQL-LOAD56]] launched with the following parameters: [{Time=1590853755581}]

I am wondering how can i restart the job if my job fails because everytime when my job fails , it runs a new instance since it picks up the current time (passed as job parameter)

How do i restart my failed job with old time parameter(mentioned above) ?

Do i need to add logic to accept time parameter in my code ? if yes , how do I handle that ?

I have attached my code. I would really appreciate if someone can help me what am i missing here in order to restart my failed job.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Db2MySqlLoadApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private Job job;


public static void main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(Db2MySqlLoadApplication.class, args);
}


@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {


    JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addLong("Time" ,System.currentTimeMillis())
            .toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(job, params);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use Spring Boot, you don't really need to implement `CommandLineRunner`. Spring Boot already provides the `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner` that does that for you. What you can do is remove this `run` method (note that the `args` parameter is not used in your case) and launch your job from the command line with something like:

```
java -jar myjob.jar Time=$(date +%s)
```

This example uses the `date +%s` command on unix/linux which gives the current date as a timestamp since the Unix epoch, you would need to look for an equivalent if you are on MS windows.

With that, if you want to restart a specific job instance with a previous `Time` parameter, you can pass the previous value as follows:

```
java -jar myjob.jar Time=1590853755581
```